# Create a google analytics filtered views profile for SmartTV

Tags: google-analytics, smart-tv

With google analytics its easy to create a filtered views profile for Mobile , Tablet or Desktop. But I cant find a way to create it for smart tv ( tv with browser integrated into it). Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the http-agent and add a custom variable in your analytics code so that it is associated with a specific user agent. To know what user agent string a device is using filter the traffic with Wireshark. Both Sony and Samsung have identifier in the user agent strings, not sure about LG, but I would assume its the same.